# Query to group files together by a unique box number and return the min/max range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a Google sheet that list of files with a corresponding box number(Col1)labeled "Box Number". I want to be able to gather all files by each unique box number and then return the min and max number(Col5) labeled "Registry ID 1" of each box. For example, Box 1 Min is 1 and Max is 10, Box 2 Min is 11 and Max is 20, and so on. If I haven't explained it well enough or you need more info let me know.

| Box Number | Registry ID 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| ---------- | -------------- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

[Link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z8vsY87a3fzxSf3cUDT-bu8NDSQhmQTRBxbBxuqGLxI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/170367/edit) the [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) in the question and insert a reasonable amount of _representative_ sample data, including the values in the two columns mention, together with another table that shows your exact _manually entered_ desired results from that sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

```
=query( 
  'Boxes Returned to NPRC'!A1:E, 
  "select A, min(E), max(E) 
   where E is not null 
   and E <> 'SKIP' 
   group by A", 
  1 
)
```

See [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343).